# overrideUserInterfaceStyle breaks SwiftUI animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm not sure if there any potential workaround for this, but here is the steps to reproduce this issue:

- Create `UIWindow` either with `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`;
- Assign `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` with `.light` for `UIWindow` or change it in `Info.plist`
- Assign `UIHostingViewController` with SwiftUI view as a `rootViewController` for `UIWindow`;
- Create any repeatForever animation in SwiftUI view;
- Go to background and then foreground.

Actual result: repeatForever stop repeating.

Sample app to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/denandreychuk/overrideUserInterfaceStyle

Comment: Hey, it looks like a good question, but it is not reproducible ( yes i know you gave some instructions, but it is too much to ask in a forum like so) and we can't run or test it, can you provide some code and some media for the error you see?

Comment: Attached temporarily SwiftUI view at least in this aspect

Comment: @grandsirr added sample app to reproduce the issue:)